# Search and get value from JSON using Node.js

Tags: node.js

I need to search "Info" from below json and get response as below using node.js.

Please help on this.

JSON File

```
{
      "call": "Info",
      "locator": "test.so",
      "classname": "DeviceInfo",
      "autostart": true,
      "state": "activated",
       "module": "Plugin",
}
```

Response

```
Info,test.so,DeviceInfo,true,activated,Plugin
```

I have tried below and printing only Info not all data's.I need to search with Info not call

```
var fs = require("fs");
var content = fs.readFileSync("D:/Test1.json");
var objectValue = JSON.parse(content);
console.log(objectValue.call);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what it means to 'search "Info"'? The sample output you've provided is merely all of the JSON values above joined with commas, so I can't see what searching was done to get it.

Comment: my requirement is to search "Info" keyword from JSON File and parse information related to Info using node.js

Comment: I have given what i have tried as well

Comment: The problem is very poorly defined... it's not much of a *search* if you want to end up simply printing all of the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `Object.values(...)` as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

```js
var fs = require("fs");
var content = fs.readFileSync("D:/Test1.json");
var objectValue = JSON.parse(content);
// output: [ 'Info', 'test.so', 'DeviceInfo', true, 'activated', 'Plugin' ]
```